# How can we change the background image of button by pressing or hovering on the button?

Tags: qt

I have made a round button and i have set a background image on it. I want it to display the other background button image while hover over it.

Comment: How did you set the background image? Also are you using a custom button class, or is it a standard QPushButton?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using style sheets:

```
QPushButton:hover { color: white }
```

See more about pseudo states [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/stylesheet-syntax.html#pseudo-states).